# zend framework display/process form using same action/view?

Tags: model-view-controller, zend-framework, view, zend-form

Using MVC architecture (Zend Framework), should you use a single view with if statements to display/process a form, or multiple views (i.e. one view to display form, one to display result).

In this instance, I am trying to produce a google like search engine.  The layout of the page will fundamentally change when displaying search results.

For example; Controller:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
        if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
            // display form
        } else {
            if ($this->_request->isPost()) { 
                if (!$form->isValid($formData)) {
                    // re-display form with errors
                } else { 
                    // process form and;
                    // display result using same action/view?
                    // display result using same action but use a different view?
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Using the same view:

```
<?php if(isset($this->form)) : ?>
    <!-- show form -->
<?php else: ?>
    <!-- show result -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Voting to close as not a real question. You have thought about the problem and you have all the tools to make a decision that suits your needs. You're just trying to delegate the decision to SO users, which won't work because one will say one thing and the other another thing. Do it in the way you think it's best, if it turns out to be a suboptimal solution, refactor.

Comment: @markus, I think answer here just not simple, but possible. It's also include if's. May be this question should be moved to programmers.SE

Comment: @markus "Should you use a single view with if statements to display/process a form, or multiple views".  Although missing the punctuation, that sounds like a question to me!  Thanks to those that provided answers, seperate views seems to be the way forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't get caught up in the old monolithic style of coding where one hunk of code does everything for one output page. The whole point of MVC is so separate responsibility. Think of a view as a template for a single piece of output, regardless of what page/url it appears on. The form is one piece of output. The search results is another. Use two views.

Answer (score 0):

Less if-s -- less bugs. I propose you to use more different views here, that can reuse one form.